# Add footer to pdf using pdfkit in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am working in a project that needs generate a pdf document from the output of an algorithm. One feature is a footer message that is shared among several pages. I am using a npm module pdfkit but a can't find a way achieving this. 
I tried to calculate footer height and I use it with the height option but in this way the text is clipped and no new page is added.
There is a way to achieve this using pdfkit npm module?